# How to fetch data on database and display in “select” dropdown

Tags: php

I have created a simple code that will fetch data from database and then display it in a  dropdown on the web page.

I'm trying to get data from a specific field from database to a display page. So far, I have tried the code below (which is not working):

database

```
CREATE TABLE `cww_avid_worktype` (
  `idworkType` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_added` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `cww_avid_worktype` (`idworkType`, `name`, `amount_added`) VALUES
(1, 'Abstract Help', 20.40),
(2, 'Admission/Application Papers', 20.30),
(3, 'Annotated Bibliography', 12.00),
(4, 'Appendices Help', 23.00),
(5, 'Article ', 23.00),
```

display.php

```
<select name="worktype" id="worktype">
        <?php
        include("db.php");
        $query = $conn->query("SELECT idworkType,amount_added,name FROM cww_avid_worktype"); // Run your query
        echo '<select name="worktype" id="worktype" class="form-control">';
        foreach ($work_type as $worktype) {
        if ($idworkType == $post['worktype']) {
        echo '<option selected="selected" id="' . $idworkType . 'wt" value="' . $idworkType . '" title="' . $amount_added . '">' . $name . '</option>';
        } else {
        echo '<option id="' . $idworkType . 'wt" value="' . $idworkType . '" title="' . $amount_added . '">' . $name . '</option>';
        }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working?

Comment: @Dharman data is not been fetched from database. Did you run? is it working on your  side?

Comment: Are you sure? Tell us what are the contents of `$query`? It looks just like a typo.